# C# divide float up into single component integers

Tags: c#, floating-point, int

I am simulating a digital display in Unity, and I need to know to break down a float into a series of individual ints.

For Example

if my float is 32.548

I need five individual ints 3,2,5,4,8. I also need one extra integer variable which is how many digits follow the decimal point. In this case 3.

It would be useful to have the 5 ints placed into an array, as in myIntegerArray[0] = 3
myIntegerArray[1] = 2
and so on. But that's not so important, the important part is the code to divide the float up into individual ints.
Once I have those I can used them to control which materials are displayed on a series of different objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var asString = 32.548.ToString();
var decimalPartLength = asString.Split('.').Last().Length;
var digitArray = asString.Where(char.IsDigit).Select(char.GetNumericValue).ToArray();
```

Comment: Tried this code out and haven't tested everything, it's looking vert promising. Had little problem because I wasn't using system.linq. But now it seems to be fine. Thanks a million for the code, this was the easiest for me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to convert the floating point value to a string, remove the dot, and then process it character by character.

The length of the string would also give you the amount of digits, once you remove the dot and the negative sign (if any).

Example:

```
float value = 32.548;
string temp = value.ToString("0.00000");
temp = temp.Replace(".", "").Replace("-", "");
int numDigits = temp.Length;
int myIntegerArray[numDigits];
for (int i = 0; i < numDigits; i++)
{
   myIntegerArray[i] = Int32.Parse(temp[i]);
}
```

Comment: Ty for the reply! Everyone has suggest similar systems, converting to string first then inserting into array. I am going to go through and try each one in turn. Thanks again!

Comment: My pleasure. Bear in mind that this solution does not require linq, since you explicitly said you are developing on Unity. Although pretty powerful, linq may be slower or not fully compatible with your target platform. If you like this solution, feel free to upvote ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var sValue = Convert.ToString(32.548);

        var normalized = sValue.Where(s => char.IsDigit(s));

        var charArray = sValue.ToArray();

        var numArray = normalized.Select(num => char.GetNumericValue(num)).ToList();

        numArray.ForEach(num => Console.WriteLine(num));
    }
}
```

Comment: could probably use regex instead of replace, but above is a hello world example

Comment: Regex is probably overkill.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by converting the floating point number to a string, and then processing the characters:

```
Double d = 32.548;
String s = Convert.ToString(d);
IEnumerable<Int32> ints =
  s
  .Where(c => Char.IsDigit(c))
  .Select(c => Convert.ToInt32(c.ToString()));

Int32 indexOfDecimal = s.IndexOf('.');
Int32 decimalPlaces = (indexOfDecimal == -1) ? 0 : (s.Length - indexOfDecimal) - 1;
```

Comment: Thanks Chris!! I am trying to understand exactly what the last line is saying here... especially the part before the colon:
       (indexOfDecimal == -1) ? 0 :
Is that like an if statement?

Comment: Yes, it's a [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator).  I included it in case the value is a whole number (e.g. `Double d = 32`).  The statement basically says: "If there isn't a decimal point, then return zero, else return the number of characters to the right of the decimal point (-1 so it doesn't include the decimal point itself)".

Comment: Ahhh that makes it really clear, I get it now!! Thanks so much. In this case the == -1 is saying if indexOfDecimal doesn't have a value, not in the null sense I guess, it's value is "no value" sort of, that's really hard to phrase xD